# Showing CP-rule is not optimal for $P \mid p_j = 1, \text{ intree} \mid \sum C_j$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization

We are asked to find a counterexample that shows that the Critical Path rule is not optimal for  $P \mid p_j = 1, \text{ intree} \mid \sum C_j$. However, after trying for two hours, I don't think I'll find one any time soon.

Does anyone of you know a counterexample? I am really curious.

Answer (score 0):

Take the directed graph G=(V,A) V={1,...,9}, A={(2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,3), (6,5),...,(9,5)} and P=3.

Make a picture and you can see easily check that there is a schedule where job 4 gets scheduled first on some machine with cost $\sum C_j^{CP} -1$